# Any specific use of double negation (!!) before new?

Tags: javascript

I understand the basic concept of double-negation- conversion to bool - this is a question about the specific use before new.

I was looking for a way to detect blob support and came across this check on [this page](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/580):

> try {   !!new Blob(); } catch (e) {   return false; }

I created an example below to demonstrate the check always failing.

```js
window.onload=function()
{
  var inputBox = document.getElementById('inputBox');
  try {
    !!new Foo15514();
    inputBox.value='supported';
  } catch (e) {
    inputBox.value='not supported';    
  }
}
```

```html
<input id='inputBox' type=text/>
```

Without getting into whether this is a good approach for blob detection or not, the question I have is what is the point of the `!!` in this case? As far as I can tell it is superfluous, but I thought I would ask in case there is something I am missing.

`!!new Foo15514()`, `new Foo15514()`, `var j = new Foo15514()` all have the same result.

**Update**
Just to get the ball rolling - one thought I had is that this was done to force the javascript engine to evaluate this rather than skipping it since it has no effect, which seems like a bad approach if that was the case.

Comment: @michaelpri did you read the first sentence? I understand `!!`. This is a specific question about use before new in the sample shown.

Comment: I dont think it is a duplicate. OP clearly states he knows what it is but is asking about its purpose/ necessity in this particular case

Comment: !! does nothing here as the `Foo1234()` call triggers an exception before it can be used

Comment: @PatrickEvans - thanks for confirming. Possibly the snippet in the reference was just taken out of context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it is indeed superfluous. Using the [`!` operator twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/784929/1048572) just casts  a value to boolean.

However, the code you read in that bug report is not complete (like a typo). It omitted an important part of what was actually meant. If you check the [commit that was made](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/pull/582/files), the picture looks different:

```
function test() {
    try {
        return !!new Blob();
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```